# C++ vector<'Object'> return type function imlementation

Tags: c++

I have the following program, and it works fine if I implement the algorithm in the main function of the program. If I make an another function of my algorithm I can not use that, and I do not know what the problem is. Should I use some pointer to solve the problem? Could someone help me please? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Map
{
public:
    float x;
    float y;
    float theta;
};
bool operator<(const Map& x, const Map& y)
{
    return x.theta < y.theta;
}
```

My sorting and filtering algorithm works fine, when I implement it in the main function:

```
int main()
{
Map mapArray[10] = {{1, 5, 1}, {9, 2, -0.8}, {3, 0, -6.5}, {5, 7, -4.3}, {1, -4, -0.99}, {6, 4, -0.66}, {10, 8, 6}, {0, 9, 1.1}, {6, 2, 4}, {3, 5, -0.8}};


    vector<Map> resultMap;
    int mapSize = (sizeof mapArray / sizeof mapArray[0]);
    float piHalf = 1.57;
    // Sort the map
    std::sort(mapArray + 0, mapArray + mapSize);
    // Filter the result
    for( int a = 0; a < mapSize; a = a + 1 )
        {
            if(mapArray[a].theta >-piHalf && mapArray[a].theta<piHalf) {
            resultMap.push_back(mapArray[a]);
            }
        }

    // Print each theta-data for test the program
    cout << "Data:" << resultMap.size()<<endl;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < resultMap.size(); i = i + 1 )
        {
            cout << "Data:" << resultMap[i].theta<<endl;
        }
   return 0;
}
```

But if I make a function of my sorting and filtering algorithm, the whole thing is not working, and I got a 0 sized vector as a result. My function implementation:

```
vector<Map> sortAndFilterMap(Map mapArray[]) {

    // Init variables
    vector<Map> resultMap;
    int mapSize = (sizeof mapArray / sizeof mapArray[0]);
    float piHalf = 1.57;
    // Sort the map
    std::sort(mapArray + 0, mapArray + mapSize);
    // Filter the result
    for( int a = 0; a < mapSize; a = a + 1 )
        {
            if(mapArray[a].theta >-piHalf && mapArray[a].theta<piHalf) {
            resultMap.push_back(mapArray[a]);
            }
        }
    return resultMap;
    }
```

How I use it in the main:

```
int main() {
Map mapArray[10] = {{1, 5, 1}, {9, 2, -0.8}, {3, 0, -6.5}, {5, 7, -4.3}, {1, -4, -0.99}, {6, 4, -0.66}, {10, 8, 6}, {0, 9, 1.1}, {6, 2, 4}, {3, 5, -0.8}};

    vector<Map> resultMap;
    resultMap = sortAndFilterMap(mapArray);



    // Print each theta-data for test the program
    cout << "Data:" << resultMap.size()<<endl;
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < resultMap.size(); i = i + 1 )
        {
            cout << "Data:" << resultMap[i].theta<<endl;
        }
   return 0;
}
```

Edit:  I am so sorry, I did not explained my error well. The error is the following: As you can see, at the end of the main function I printed out my filtered and sorted map. In the first solution when I made the implementation in the main loop, I got the expected values printed. When I make a function the "theta" values should be printed out also, but I got nothing printed. Before the for loop, I "cout" the size of the resultMap, but I got 0, instead of 6.

Comment: "It is not working" doesn't say what the error is. Give us the error.

Comment: If I were you , I didn't write `using namespace std;`.

Comment: I am so sorry. The error is the following: As you can see, at the end of the main function I printed out my filtered and sorted map. In the first solution when I made the implementation in the main loop, I got the expected values printed. When I make a function  the "theta" values should be printed out also, but I got nothing printed. Before the for loop, I "cout" the size of the resultMap, but I got 0, instead of 6.

Comment: I suggest you do not name your class `Map`. It is confusing, as `map`is already used in the std library to name a associative array container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int mapSize = (sizeof mapArray / sizeof mapArray[0]);
```

This line only works in very few situations. It's easier to just say that you should not do this. Pass the length of the array as extra parameter and you are safe:

```
std::vector<Map> sortAndFilterMap(Map mapArray[], int mapSize)
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::vector<Map>` everywhere and remove the raw arrays alltogether.

Comment: @Emadpres It's called [array decay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: I add the length of the array as an extra parameter. Altough then in the main loop I used to define my length of the array with : int mapSize = (sizeof mapArray / sizeof mapArray[0]); Is there any other way to define the length of a simple array?

Comment: Well, you already set the size as fixed, so you could as well say `const int MapSize = 10;` There is no way to actually *get* the size of an array once you are in another function. You need the extra value.

Comment: The idiomatic way of doing this in C++ would be to have `std::vector<Map> sortAndFilterMap( Map const* begin, Map const* end )`, and invoke it with `sortAndFilterMap( std::begin( mapArray ), std::end( mapArray )`.  At least, in the cases where you really need a C style array.  (In his particular case, I'd do everything with `std::vector`.)

Comment: @mirind4 To get the length of a C style array: `std::end( array ) - std::begin( array )`..

Answer (score 2):

The results of `int mapSize = (sizeof mapArray / sizeof mapArray[0]);` are different in the two cases:

1. When it's in main: the result is 10, which is what you expect.
2. When it's in `vector<Map> sortAndFilterMap(Map mapArray[])`: the array decays into a pointer to a Map object (the function doesn't know the size of the mapArray anymore); `sizeof mapArray` returns the size of such pointer (4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you're on a 32 or 64-bit system). Thus the result is `(4 or 8) / (sizeof float * 3) = 0`. The for loop will break immediately on the first iteration and the function returns an empty vector.

Comment: nice explanation, now i understand why I had the problem, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to encourage use of raw C arrays, which should basically never be used except in *very* special situations. But, if one really must, you could use this:

```
template<size_t mapSize>
vector<Map> sortAndFilterMap(Map (&mapArray)[mapSize]) {
```

A reference to an array `(&mapArray)` can use template deduction to deduce the size of the array. In this `mapSize` will have the correct size.

Anyway, just use `vector`s instead of C arrays by default.

Comment: Even better mighty be to have `sortAndFilterMap` take two iterators, and pass it `std::begin( mapArray )` and `std::end( mapArray )`.